# Eclipse Android Motodev and PHP integration

Tags: php, android, eclipse

I have both the Motodev Android Eclipse and a PHP Eclipse installation running on my windows system. They share the workspace and both PHP and Android projects appear in both, however each instance is configured for only one language/environment.

Is there any way to integrate the two IDEs so I don't have to switch between them. Can I add PHP support to Motodev Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

> > Is there any way to integrate the two IDEs so I don't have to switch between them. Can I add PHP support to Motodev Eclipse?

Yes, you can do that in Motodev. Just install the PDT. Go to *Window* -> *Install Software*, choose Elios from the list. Then, select *Programming Languages* -> *PHP Development Tools*:

[image]

Follow the wizard and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. "Install Software" is under "Help" (not "Window") in my version of Motodev, but I got it to work after a little searching.

Answer (score 0):

As Christian points out, this is one way to do it.  You can also do the reverse, which is to install the MOTODEV functionality into your own Eclipse install.  We have a full plugin archive with all the dependent projects available from the download site at developer.motorola.com.  When you use it, uncheck the "Contact all sites" box because it's not necessary.  I don't advise trying to use the update site just now because we're seeing some connection problems.