# How to install motodev core plugins for android on eclipse juno?

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, motodev-studio

After many searching the web for `motodev plugin`, I found some threads about redistributing a fresh one. I made it for all android developers, it has many powerful snippets, automatic ContentProvider generator, auto activity and widget register in android manifest, and more.

This link has complete instructions: http://dev.seven-sky.ir/

Installation steps:
After downloading [motodev zip file](http://dev.seven-sky.ir) follow
        
        1. download eclipse juno for mobile from this site:
        http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
        
        2. extract it to a folder, for example *c:\eclipse* and run eclipse.
        
        3. goto menu: Help > Install New Software... > Click *Add...* button.
        
        4. in the name field type: *"Sequoyah 2.1"*, and in site field type *"http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.1/"*
        
        5. click OK and wait to list populated, select all items and then click *"Finish"*
        button.
        
        6. after installing sequoyah 2.1, install motodev core plugins in the same way,
        type *"motodev core plugins"* in name field and "file://c:\downloads\motodev-core-plugins-5.0.0-eclipse-juno.zip"
        in site field(where your download file is in c:\downloads).
        
        7. if you prompted to restart eclipse then restart it.
        
        8. after installing and restarting eclipse, enjoy two new perspectives: *"MOTODEV
            Database"* and *"MOTODEV Studio for Android"*.

Comment: why on earth would one want to use Motodev for ?

Comment: @njzk2 To do Android development?

Comment: @njzk2 the editor for translations is cool. But I don't like to install 500mb for such a small function.

Comment: thanks for the comments,
for rekire: it's not 500mb, motodev + sequoyah = 150mb
for Luksprog: as I say it has some additional useful tools.
for njzk2: many people want to get that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521608/motodev-studio-vs-android-google-plugin<br />
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993204/android-ide-eclipse-or-motodev-or-tegra-android-development-pack
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150996/is-motodev-faster-than-the-android-emulator
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573989/adt-plugin-directory-location-for-sdk-motodev

Comment: for njzk2:<br />
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692865/motodev-core-plugins
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219353/where-i-can-download-motodev-studio
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850262/android-project-working-on-motodev-but-crashes-on-eclipse
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312465/how-to-extend-activity-from-mapactivity-in-android-using-motodev
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746418/error-when-trying-to-install-motodev-core-plugin
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809101/explain-motodev-validator-errors

Comment: for njzk2:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822496/eclipse-android-motodev-and-php-integration
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857237/motodev-library-project
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334042/motodev-studio-issue-with-sdk-install
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477048/how-to-update-motodev-to-android-sdk-4-2
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/motodev-studio/hot

and finally if it is not useful why google started to support that?

Comment: No Linux version. :/ Thank you anyway. I had problems to build from scratch, so I'll search for someone else who has exported the plugins.

Comment: the link is dead, i'd really like to get a working copy since i've been crazy for days trying to build it :<